# what shortcomings does couchbase have, compared to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, architecture, couchbase

I see a massive gap of popularity between MongoDB and Couchbase.

**What features\advantages does mongo have over couchbase?**

I'm deploying DB instances in a cluster, between datacenters, where all servers accept incoming requests.
Is it not simpler to do this with couchbase, that has only one server role, and less configuration?

Comment: There are many feature differences besides the server roles. I'd suggest you consider them, too, when choosing.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed correct!

It is very simple to deploy Couchbase instances and cluster them.  This is because Couchbase has a single node type which minimizes configuration, like you've mentioned.

What you might not know is that Couchbase has a built in caching layer, eliminating the need to install other caching services to sit next to your database.  This puts an emphasis on performance, which is critical in modern database.

**UPDATE**

I am a Developer Advocate at Couchbase, and listed a few advantages for you.

Comment: "I'm a Developer Advocate for Couchbase." I believe you should declare your affiliations so the poster can weigh the answer in the fullest possible knowledge.